# using cosine and sin to find missing angles

Tags: iphone, trigonometry

how can i use cosine and sine in my iphone application to find the missing value of angles?
if i have a float that contains a number, how can i get the cosine of that angle. i used this example however it gave me errors

```
        double x1float = (cos(pfloat));
```

Comment: What errors? You're aware that the build-in cos and sin work in radians not degrees? (And what do you mean the missing values?)

Comment: -1: Question is not clear at all.  What is the error?

Comment: no i figured out the error sorry, i tried setting it to degress and the error came from there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error does it give you? Did you include math.h, assuming this is C code?

Comment: ... and link against libm? (`-lm` on the link step command line)

Comment: i did include <math.h>it says expected expression before double